# How to display paragraphs and images from div in order?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a small web-tool where editors can write content by using buttons to add paragraphs and images. I store the elements with an id ((number of element) starting at 0 and incremented for every new element) and load with a button in order to a div "preview" where the content is supposed to be displayed as in the web page later on.

My issue is that, for a reason I don't understand, the image is always displayed below all the paragraphs instead of being in order. Presumably there is an easy fix, but I am very new to HTML, CSS and JS and couldn't find the solution online.
Sorry if this is a stupid mistake or the solution was already posted somewhere.

Javascript handling the preview rendering:

```js
// Preview current document status
document.getElementById("previewButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
   // Clear
   document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = "";

   // Add all elements properly
   var section = document.getElementById("preview");
   var id = "preview";

   for (var counter = 0; counter < element_counter; counter++) {
      var type = document.getElementById(counter).nodeName;

      // If text element
      if (type === "TEXTAREA") {
         var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
         var text = document.getElementById(counter).value;
         paragraph.setAttribute("id", id + counter);
         paragraph.setAttribute("class", "flow-text");
         paragraph.append(text);
         section.appendChild(paragraph);
      }

      // If image element
      if (type === "INPUT") {
         var file = document.getElementById(counter).files[0];
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onload = function(e) {
            var image = document.createElement("img");
            image.setAttribute("id", id + counter);
            image.setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
            image.setAttribute("class", "materialboxed responsive-img");
            section.appendChild(image);
         }
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
   }
});
```

[image]

Comment: OP is saying that the images appear as a group below the paragraphs. This likely has to do with the `reader.onload()` being triggered (in time) more slowly than the rest of the code.

Comment: @volt I did not mean to display images inline next to text but simply avoid the order of paragraphs and images to be mixed up as all images move down to the bottom.

Comment: @GetSet How could I avoid this? I thought since the loop iterates in order it would be displayed that way, can I fix this by adding a delay or is there a smarter solution for this?

Comment: What order are you expecting?

Comment: @EternalHour I linked a picture in my post now, let's say the user enters in the editor an image (id=0), a textarea "Some text" (id=1) next another textarea "more text" (id=2). The preview is supposed to load first id=0 then id=1 and then id=2 i.e. iterative for-loop. However my code would now display. "Some text"(id=1), below "more text"(id=2) and then the image(id=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work. I can't test though without your code. However basically the principle at work is to *isolate* some of the vars so they represent distinct instantiations. And then immediately add the image element to the DOM. The `reader.onload` is expected to run asynchronously still.

```
enter code here if (type === "INPUT") {

    (function() {
        var file = document.getElementById(counter).files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.setAttribute("id", id + counter);
        image.setAttribute("class", "materialboxed responsive-img");
        section.appendChild(image);

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            image.setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }());
}
```